# Get and change radius size of Node - Sprite-Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode, skshapenode

I am using Swift and SpriteKit and I create a new circle (as a Node) like this

```
 var circlePlayer = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
```

and I would like to access later on the radius of the circle in order to get its value or modify it (increase it by 1 for instance) - how can I achieve this?

Comment: subclass skshapenode, add radius property. or just add it to the node's userData dictionary.

Comment: `let radius = (circlePlayer.frame.size.width-1.0)/2.0`

Comment: @LearnCocos2D how do I add this property to the userData dictionary, and then access it?

Answer (score 1):

Scale it. `circlePlayer.setScale(2)`

Check out: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/setScale:

Comment: Okay thanks, what if I want to get the radius value? or want to increase the radius by 1?

Comment: Just scale it by new radius / old radius

Comment: Yes but I need a way to get the value of the 'old radius', how can I do that?

Comment: keep track of it in property?

Comment: Use the node's frame (node.frame)